# Indexing an Oracle IOT by non-pk fields

Tags: oracle, clustered-index

I have a table in SQL Server that needs its normal pk index to be replaced by a clustered index on two fields. These other fields are **not** part of the primary key.

I need to do something similar in Oracle. As far as I know, this can be done using index-ordered tables, but my guess is these indexes are only constructed on the primary key.

Is there any way I can get a similar behavior to SQLServer's clustered index in Oracle?

Comment: If you replace the pk by something else this 'else' becomes the PK, so where is the problem?

Comment: Thanks for answering.

The problem with replacing the pk is that this table is already widely used, and the fields by which I need to index the table are not unique. Because of this reason, the primary key cannot be replaced.

Comment: why wouldn't a regular index on the Oracle table be sufficient?

Comment: At the moment I was looking for a way to simulate the clustered index functionality in Oracle. But it had to be what you say: a regular index without physical ordering.

Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Index organized tables are the concept of oracle which is near to clustered indexes in sql server. I found a [discussion](http://kr.forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=951103&tstart=15) about the topic in oracle forum and one on [asktom](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:4514641276987).

My question is: why do you want to adapt the behavior? What is the benefit you whant to obtain?

A clustered index in sql server is mostly the primary key index. Rowdata is stored into the index node. The conecpt on oracle to store row data into the index is an index organized table. 
On oracle the iot is used to avoid a second lookup for row data into the table after index lookup.

The purpose of clustered index on sql server is to store the rowdata. A table can have only one clustered index. This index will hold the rowdata. Any other index is a non clustered index.

IMHO the concept of clustered index is bound to sql server data storage and there is no need to rebuild this behavior in oracle. Oracle has other concepts to store data.

**Answer:**
A regular index on oracle is all to solve your problem.